# Auctex's siunitx macro absorbs a backslash

Tags: latex, auctex

If I insert `\SI{50}{\m}` into a latex file with auctex and `LaTeX-environment` doesn't insert the backslash before `m`, i.e. `\SI{50}{m}` instead of `\SI{50}{\m}`. However the backslash is required such that things like `\SI{50}{\m\per\s}` work.

Is this a bug or do I use this function in the wrong way? In the first case: is there a workaround? In the second case: Why does this behaviour make sense and how is the correct use in this case.

My auctex-version is 11.88.6 and my emacs version 24.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known bug (due to a breaking change on Emacs's side), see https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19504, but it should have been fixed in AUCTeX 11.89